# display new WordPress page content

Tags: pages

Hi I create a WordPress site from scratch 
I can creat a custom template like this page-mypagename and add content with php and HTML code  it's work.

But when i create a new page on admin dashboard
And I add text, the text content does not display on my new page.

Could someone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your code that you are using for that page ? It will be more helpful to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to select the new template as your page's template while creating a new page. To do this, choose the new template under *"Page Attributes"* setting just like below screenshot:

[image: New page template]

Now, you should make sure you are outputting the content in your page. Create a simple loop, and use `the_content()` within:

```
while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    the_content();
}
```

Now your content will be displayed in your new page template.

**PS:** Image credits goes to [WP Beginners](http://wpbeginner.com)